# Fastest serialization/deserialization scheme for a Datastructure

Tags: android, serialization, data-structures, sax, protocol-buffers

I have an android application that uses a datastructure consisting couple of binary trees and other structures like list and arrays all linked to each other. i would like you all to suggest a scheme for saving and retriving this data structure. the data structure is created through a SAX parses (the source is XML file). i have tried java serialization/de-serialization but find it atleast twice as slow as using the original SAX parser to build the structure.
              the serailzation(RAM to storage) time is not of high importance has it will take place as a background process, but i want a faster deserialisation(storage to RAM) scheme.

i dont want any type checking features etc. all i want is a fast serailization and faster deserialization scheme. also is Google's Protocol Buffer a good candidate? please suggest ..

(note: my app will be show a blank window(Activity) untill the datastructure is deserialised, so speed is of highest importance and i have skinned down my DS to the utmost possible)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your app HAVE to show a white screen?  Throw a splash up and do the heavy lifting in the background.  If its going to take more than about 0.75 to 1 seconds, from a usability standpoint, you should do this anyways.  But im also curious as to how others handle ser, watching this thread  :)

Comment: While i like protocol buffer some ppl say it's slower and worse than http://msgpack.org/

Comment: @yep: yeah my application takes around 3 seconds to parse the entire datastructure.. i do have a progress bar but would like to shorten the latency..

Comment: @mibollma Thanks will try messagepack too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default de/serialization is usually quite slow for it relies on reflection extensively (which is slow). You can try to implement it manually by [redefining readObject/writeObject](http://www.javablogging.com/what-are-writeobject-and-readobject-customizing-the-serialization-process/) on your class, it usually gives noticeable performance boost.